# What does using parentheses instead of quotes do when binding input data to an Angular component in the template?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have just come across this code:

```
<pagination (selectRowChange)="changeSelectRow($event)"
                        [total]=(total)
                        [(currentPage)]="currentPage"
                        [(pageSize)]="pageSize"
                        [pageSizes]="pageSizes"
                        [start]=(start)
                        [end]=(end)
                        [dataFiltered]=(dataFiltered)
                        [maxPage]=(maxPage)
                        (goToPage)="goToPage($event)"
                        (searchSubmit)="search($event)"
                        [filteredTotal]=(filteredTotal)
                        [status]="isDataAvailable">
            </pagination>
```

total and start inputs take values that are wrapped in brackets. Ive never seen this before and I cant find what it does?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the component code for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has no effect on the input binding.

```
<div [attr.title]="name"></div>
<div [attr.title]='name'></div>
<div [attr.title]=[name]></div>
<div [attr.title]=(name)></div>
```

All the above work the same way.

I can only image that the original programmer wrote it by mistake. The web browser is **correcting** the mistake when it parses the HTML.

It does look strange, because we already use `()[]{}` symbols for bindings. The issue here is that Angular is still restricted to the same limitations as HTML. If the browser accepts this as a valid attribute assignment, then it's going to work.

There is a chance this will trigger an error during AOT compiling, but I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

- parentheses () use of event binding  `<button (click)="readRainbow($event)">`
- bracket [] for property binding `<input [value]="firstName">`
- the can be used together to setup two way data binding `<my-cmp [(title)]="name">`
- bracket [] use with directives like here `<div [ngClass]="{'active': isActive, 'disabled': isDisabled}">`

this link have all the details about this topic  [angular guide cheatsheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)